# Where can I find an endogeneity proof for bias by LLN?

Tags: econometrics, statistics, proof

It is intuitive that E[xe] is non-zero but the result E[xe]=sigma(x)*sigma(e)*corr(xe) seems odd. Please help point me in the right direction.

Comment: $\sigma_x\sigma_ecorr(xe)=cov(x,e)$ by definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient. Now $cov(x,e)=E[xe]-E[x]E[e]$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance

Comment: That's quite elegant. Thank you, @guest12382.